# Implement Spring Library Tracking (Mobile App Sensor)

Tags: ios, objective-c, spring-mvc, linker-errors, symbol-not-found

I need to implement **Spring Tracking Library** in my project.

I researched a lot over net and could not find a proper demo for it.

What all I found is this **[link](https://confluence.spring.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30310670#MobileAppSensor%28EnglishVersion%29-ImplementationiOS)** which demonstrates on how to implement this in your project but I am getting error in this.

This **[link](https://confluence.spring.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26902690)** gives the required library for the above implementation.

Any idea on how to implement this.

**This is the code i have implemented but getting error in this.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SpringOEWA.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

SpringOEWA* spring;


@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    spring = [[SpringOEWA alloc] initWithSiteAndApplication:@"app" application:@"Test App"];
    spring.timeout = 30.0; // in seconds
    spring.debug = YES;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"service/messaging/email",@"cp",nil];
    [spring commit:dict];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**Following error is prompted for the .a library I have imported.**

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xyz/Desktop/TestnewSpring/spring-appsensor-iOS-oewa-1.3.2/spring-appsensor-device-oewa.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/xyz/Desktop/TestnewSpring/spring-appsensor-iOS-oewa-1.3.2/spring-appsensor-device-oewa.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in spring-appsensor-fat-oewa.a(SpringOEWA.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "AdSupport.framework" to your Project/Build Phases. That worked for me.